# async-await не работает глобальная переменная

Tags: javascript, async-await

Присваивание до `await`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Присваивание после `await`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первом случае переменной присвоилось значение, а во втором нет. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код текстом, чтобы его можно было скопировать и запустить. Это сильно повысит шансы получить хороший ответ. Вы можете это сделать, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Асинхронные функции запускаются и начинают исполняться синхронно, их асинхронность начинается с await. Поэтому в первом случае присваивание внутри функции успевает произойти до вывода в консоль вне функции, в отличие от второго случая.

Сравните:

```js
async function foo() {
  console.log(1);
  await Promise.resolve();
  console.log(3);
};

foo();
console.log(2);
```